# 2015 Community Moderator Election - Nomination Requests

Tags: discussion, election

In the light of the currently running nomination phase of the [2015 Community Moderator Election](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5569/2015-community-moderator-election), I want to add this question as a place for the community to nudge candidates on the edge into actually nominating themselves.

This seems to be customary around the network:

> Some sites like to host a thread where people can try to goad others
> into nominating by naming them and saying "Oi I think you should run
> for these very many awesome reasons" - Grace Note <sub>[in the Election Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/25330?m=22457226#22457226)</sub>

So here it is, oh and a small reminder

#### Please don't prod further, when "nominated" candidates decline!

Answer (score 15):

I nominate [Simon André Forsberg](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-andr%c3%a9-forsberg).  I, and several users in chat, think he would make a good moderator for the site.

## Update

#### [Nomination Accepted!](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-95217)

Answer (score 12):

[200_Success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success)

Current protem moderator. Not much to say really. I'd like to see you stay on and provide some extra continuity as we move toward full fledged graduation. We all understand if you would like to step down. All three of you have earned some rest IMO, but we would still love to see you stay on. You've been a great mod and there's no reason to think that would change.

[***Nomination Accepted***](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-95866)

Answer (score 10):

[Heslacher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29371/heslacher) has been quietly clearing the queues, editing questions, and nudging new users in the right direction for quite some time now. Not only is he patient and kind, he's technically very sharp as well. Has a great sense for what's on/off topic here. Doesn't chat much, but seems to always be lurking in there just a ping away.

If you've not considered it, please do. I think you'd make a great moderator.

Answer (score 10):

## [janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos)

He's been one of the most active answerers on Code Review for a while, is currently the top 3 user based on reputation. He's friendly in chat and friendly in comments. Overall I think he would be a good candidate.

## Update

#### [Nomination Accepted!](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-95282)

Answer (score 8):

I think [mjolka](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/44723/mjolka) would be a good candidate.  From my experience, he is helpful and friendly, and he lives on the other side of the world, so we could have a moderator around at 3:00 AM in the morning (CST/CDT).

Answer (score 7):

## [DECLINED](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22533330#22533330)

---

I think that [@JeroenVannevel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/21028/jeroen-vannevel) would be a good Moderator as well. He has more than once been there to help me understand coding aspects, and also had the patience to explain things to me through chat.

I know that he is in a different Time Zone than a majority of the users on CR as well, so it would make a good overlap as well.

Answer (score 7):

## [@Vogel612](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37660/vogel612)

Vogel612 knows the SE network very well, and has a very good sense to guide off-topic posts to the right places. This should come handy when we start getting more traffic (which we surely will). He's a great reviewer too, and taught me quite a few new tricks. Over the year or so that I've known him, he's evolved visibly. He takes criticism well, listens to reason and improves. He deals with conflicts very well. I'd expect him to be a level-headed, fair, and wise mod.

#### [Nomination accepted.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination#post-95613)