# 2021 Community Moderator Election - Nomination Requests

Tags: discussion, election

In light of the currently running nomination phase of the [2021 Community Moderator Election](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/3), I want to add this question as a place for the community to nudge candidates on the edge into actually nominating themselves.

We had this for the [2015 election](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5579/2015-community-moderator-election-nomination-requests) and I kind of missed it in the 2018 election.
We're not the first site to think of something like that:

> Some sites like to host a thread where people can try to goad others
> into nominating by naming them and saying "Oi I think you should run
> for these very many awesome reasons" - Grace Note <sub>[in the 2015 Election Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/25330?m=22457226#22457226)</sub>

So here it is, oh and a small reminder

#### Please don't prod further, when "nominated" candidates decline!

Comment: We definitely do allow these and some sites do them by default - for example, [MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4926/2021-moderator-election-suggestions-for-nominees) recently had one. It's long been a disappointment that we don't build in a way for people to nominate candidates, particularly those who might not otherwise think they'd be good mods. So, good luck to everyone. Also, please don't feel like you shouldn't nominate if you're not listed here - it's often common for some people to be overlooked. :)

Answer (score 7):

I would like to urge [Sam Onela](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120114/s%e1%b4%80%e1%b4%8d-on%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%8c%e1%b4%80) to become a moderator. They are in the 2nd Monitor almost every day. They work hard to maintain the quality of Code Review on almost a daily basis in the review queues and from the 2nd Monitor. They fight Zombies and work hard to keep our answer percentage above 90% (we need more people working on this). This is actually a recognition of someone who is already working hard as a moderator on Code Review without having the diamond.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to urge [Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75307/toby-speight) to become a moderator. They already spends more than enough time on Code Review everyday. They cares greatly about the quality of questions and answers on Code Review (they has edited quite a few of my questions and answers to improve them). They fights Zombies. They participate in the review queues everyday. I respect their opinions on posts and in the 2nd Monitor. This is actually a recognition of someone who is already working hard as a moderator on Code Review without having the diamond.